# How to send tilde or backtick in AutoHotkey using a Nordic keyboard layout?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

To bind <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to tilde ~ and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to backtick ` I wrote this [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

```
<^>!,:: Send, ~
<^>!.:: Send, ``
```

This works fine when using some keyboard layouts, for example the Italian one.

Some keyboard layouts, for example the Estonian and I believe other Nordic layouts as well, don't "fire" those symbols right away but require them to be pressed in combination with other keys. For example:

- <kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> produces `~`
- <kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> produces `õ`

With this kind of keyboard layouts the script I wrote requires the keys combination to be pressed twice and has the result of producing the symbols twice.

For example <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> produces `~~`

Is it possible to make the script work correctly, regardless of the keyboard layout used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on all keyboards that use AltGr:

```
<^>!,:: Send {text}~
<^>!.:: Send {text}`` ; backtick must be escaped by another one
```

See [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text) in the documentation.

Comment: Sending unicodes `<^>!,:: Send, {U+223C}` and `<^>!.:: Send, {U+0060}` works as well.